# lost transaction -- not back in my MEW

Tags: transactions, myetherwallet, ico, pending-transactions, revert-opcode

i sent a transaction to credits ico and it came back with a transaction failure due to a revert opcode. the credits team say they are not responsible i should take it up with ethereum. the ether-transaction (see below) did´nt go through but it has not been returend to my etherwallet. how can i get my ether back? please help me on how to solve this issue.

this is the transaction hash:
0xcf1bcbd424b5ca760669bb812d51b69a00f4b3bbfea6c54a24099231234deb5e

thank you

Comment: I lost Private Key + JSON file to open my myEtherwallet.com. Do you know how to find: - What time is a MEW wallet created? - What website that has created an Ethereum wallet? This is because I may had created this MEW from www.myetherwallet.com Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When [your transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xcf1bcbd424b5ca760669bb812d51b69a00f4b3bbfea6c54a24099231234deb5e) failed, it was automatically returned to your wallet on the blockchain, minus the gas spent on the transaction itself. If it isn't being reflected in MyEtherWallet, it's probably because it hasn't resynced with the network yet.

When a transaction get sent in ethereum, one of the following MUST happen:

- The transaction completes successfully, and the recipient has the ether they were sent.
- The transaction is aborted, and the full amount, minus gas cost, is returned back to the origin address.

There's no intermediary -- it's just that clients that aren't synced don't know the execution status of the transaction yet.

More curiously, a [subsequent transaction from your wallet](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1f61137b508c8ef3cb8c7f24af85096908e6d679bbcfba2951205dd30d325c81) to the [same contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x87a0110ed1d09af6568392e77cedae95e5f3a674) did execute a few hours after the first transaction. Perhaps you don't totally recall this happening, but you sent 0.5 ether that time -- meaning you're going to have less reflected in your balance than if the first transaction went through. Etherscan shows 0.49324782 ETH still in your account.